# There is a problem with your iPod

Tags: itunes

Tried connecting my iTouch version 3.1.3 to iTunes but itunes gives me following error:

```
 There is a problem with your iPod.
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with your iPod...

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is either a jailbroken device or a hardware error. Have you considered taking it in for service?

If iTunes thinks a restore will help, it will offer that instead of telling you to go to service, but that [might be a good thing to try](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414) if you can't or won't get it serviced.

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried restoring the iTouch, but after restoring, the iTouch gets stuck showing itunes logo. 
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83243/after-restore-shows-itunes-logo