# How do I get my iPod touch (1st gen) out of a recovery mode boot loop?

Tags: itunes, restore

I restored my iPod touch 1G and when it rebooted after completing restore, it got stuck showing the iTunes logo.

I tried two different methods of exiting the recovery mode as explained at

[How To Fix Recovery Mode Loop OR iTunes Logo on iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch](http://www.yourtechinfo.com/2012/05/how-to-fix-recovery-mode-loop-or-itunes.html)

I even tried via Snowbreeze as explained at

[How To Jailbreak Using Sn0wbreeze v2.9](http://modmyi.com/forums/how-jailbreak-guides/795416-how-jailbreak-using-sn0wbreeze-v2-9-a.html)

but these didn't work for me.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Was it a jailbroken iPod?

Comment: Actually, I don't have idea whether it is a jailbroken one. I just tried to restore my friend's iTouch.